# Vuetify: How to filter data in v-data-table?

Tags: vue.js, datatable, vue-component, vuetify.js

In a data table, I want to display only items, where the property 'display' is 'true'. There is the property 'filter' in the component [v-data-table](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables). But there is no example showing, how to use it.

I have tried several approaches, but without success. The following code snippet is also available at [codepen](https://codepen.io/antoninslejska/pen/qKwBda).

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data () {
    return {
      headers: [
        {
          text: 'Dessert (100g serving)',
          align: 'left',
          sortable: false,
          value: 'name'
        },
        { text: 'Calories', value: 'calories' },
        { text: 'Fat (g)', value: 'fat' },
        { text: 'Carbs (g)', value: 'carbs' },
        { text: 'Protein (g)', value: 'protein' },
        { text: 'Iron (%)', value: 'iron' }
      ],
      desserts: [
        {
          value: false,
          name: 'Frozen Yogurt',
          calories: 159,
          fat: 6.0,
          carbs: 24,
          protein: 4.0,
          iron: '1%',
          display: false
        },
        {
          value: false,
          name: 'Ice cream sandwich',
          calories: 237,
          fat: 9.0,
          carbs: 37,
          protein: 4.3,
          iron: '1%',
          display: true
        },
        {
          value: false,
          name: 'Eclair',
          calories: 262,
          fat: 16.0,
          carbs: 23,
          protein: 6.0,
          iron: '7%',
          display: false
        },
        {
          value: false,
          name: 'Cupcake',
          calories: 305,
          fat: 3.7,
          carbs: 67,
          protein: 4.3,
          iron: '8%',
          display: true
        },
        {
          value: false,
          name: 'Gingerbread',
          calories: 356,
          fat: 16.0,
          carbs: 49,
          protein: 3.9,
          iron: '16%',
          display: false
        },
        {
          value: false,
          name: 'Jelly bean',
          calories: 375,
          fat: 0.0,
          carbs: 94,
          protein: 0.0,
          iron: '0%',
          display: true
        },
        {
          value: false,
          name: 'Lollipop',
          calories: 392,
          fat: 0.2,
          carbs: 98,
          protein: 0,
          iron: '2%',
          display: false
        },
        {
          value: false,
          name: 'Honeycomb',
          calories: 408,
          fat: 3.2,
          carbs: 87,
          protein: 6.5,
          iron: '45%',
          display: false
        },
        {
          value: false,
          name: 'Donut',
          calories: 452,
          fat: 25.0,
          carbs: 51,
          protein: 4.9,
          iron: '22%',
          display: false
        },
        {
          value: false,
          name: 'KitKat',
          calories: 518,
          fat: 26.0,
          carbs: 65,
          protein: 7,
          iron: '6%',
          display: false
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  methods: {
    filterItems(val, search) {
      return val.display;
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700|Material+Icons' rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://unpkg.com/vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, minimal-ui">
</head>
<body>

<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-data-table
      :headers="headers"
      :items="desserts"
      hide-actions
      item-key="name"
      :filter="filterItems"
    >
      <template slot="items" slot-scope="props">
        <tr @click="props.expanded = !props.expanded" :class="[props.expanded && 'expanded']">
          <td>{{ props.item.name }}</td>
          <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.calories }}</td>
          <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.fat }}</td>
          <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.carbs }}</td>
          <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.protein }}</td>
          <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.iron }}</td>
        </tr>
      </template>
      <template slot="expand" slot-scope="props">
        <v-card flat>
          <v-card-text>Peek-a-boo!</v-card-text>
        </v-card>
      </template>
    </v-data-table>
  </v-app>
</div>

  <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/vuetify/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

The problematic part of the code is:

```
  methods: {
    filterItems(val, search) {
      return ???;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

I was struggling for a long time with this issue because I also thought :filter did not work. Later, after a lot of pain, I realised that I needed a :search prop to use :filter, and the functionality that I wanted was not the one that is provided by Vuetify.

Like you, I wanted to filter my data-table with a function that returned a boolean, i.e: true, if row should be displayed.

If someone is looking for a quick solution to do the same, a simple "v-if" should do the trick. Based on the example from above:

```
<template slot="items" slot-scope="props" v-if="props.item.display">
```

There are other solutions of course, depending on your needs, like using .filter method on the desserts array itself.

In my case, because I wanted to always display 5 rows at a time in my data-table (not using hide-actions), I ended up using the created() lifecycle hook, instead of a v-if:

```
created: function() {
this.shownDesserts = this.desserts.filter(dessert => {
  return dessert.display
})
```

},

Answer (score 2):

[Looking at the source code](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/dev/src/components/VDataTable/VDataTable.js#L44), I think you really want `custom-filter` as opposed to `filter`:

```
(items: object[], search: string, filter: Filter): object[]
```

So you would define a function and pass it as an argument to the `custom-filter` property on the table. When searching, you are provided with all the items in the table represented by an array of objects (`object[]`), the search string that was typed into the search box, and the filter function to apply against all the objects in the array, so:

```
:custom-filter="filterItems"

filterItems(items, search, filter) {
    items.filter(r => filter(r.calories > search))
}
```

The above of course is just a very rudimentary example.

Comment: It looks like that the filters (:filter, :custom-filter) do not work. I tried simply: 'filterItems(items, search, filter) { console.log(items); }', but the console stays empty. See: https://codepen.io/antoninslejska/pen/qKwBda?editors=1011

Comment: KaelWD in the issue writes:

customFilter is only called if you're using the search prop, and it gets passed filter as the third argument. The API is a bit confusing and difficult to use, but it is being improved for a future release.

Comment: @ScottBaker Are you using vuetify 2 or vuetify 1.5? They've changed their monorepo a bit.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution I came up with. I was having a similar problem where I wanted to implement a custom filter that still worked with the search. I ended up using a computed property that applies a filter to the data and that computed property is what gets sent to the table.

```
computed: {
  dataListDisplay: function() {
    return this.applyFilters(this.dataList);
  },
}
```

dataListDisplay is what you send to the v-data-table items prop. And you will need to implement the applFilters function how you'd like.

My table is read only. I imagine you'd have to be careful if you are changing the data. You may need to provide a setter for the dataListDisplay computed function.

Answer (score 0):

For props, **filter**, this should help:

```
methods: {
  filterItems(val, search) {
    return val != null && typeof val !== 'boolean' && val.toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(search) !== -1;
  }
}
```